# Android device manager keep re-adding old phone

Tags: android-device-manager

Recently i found that my old device shown up in list of devices with location in USA strange thing was that the phone was in my house and far far away from USA and phone is wiped and connected to different gmail account so I just removed it now I found that is showed up again. Does anyone have clue what is happening, or how can I contact google support to ask them about this?

[image]